# html button is requiring 2 clicks to toggle class?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamics-365, portal

I am currently struggling to get a function working with a button that has an onclick event to toggle a class. Please can you review the code and help me understand why it is needing two clicks and how to fix it.

```js
function dropdownbuttonclick(element) {
  let coll = $(".dropdown");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    //coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () { 
    $(this.firstChild).toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    //console.log(content);
    
    if (content.style.height === "auto") {
      content.style.height = "75px";
    } 
    else {
      content.style.height = "auto";
    }
    //});
  }
}
```

```js
if (row.description.length > 50) {
  return "<div width='100%' style='min-height:100px;" + backgrnd + "'><button type='button' class='dropdown' onclick='dropdownbuttonclick(this)'><i class='fa fa-solid fa-chevron-down'></i></button><div class='content' style='margin:20px;'>" + title + "</div></div>";
}
```

I have tried to change the onclick event but I am not sure how to fix.

Comment: There seems to be some errors in your code - such as the use of `this` in a global function  - I don't see how this works on any click, let alone the second one onwards.

Comment: Hi Rory, my toggle class is working. So the icon changes how I want it to and the content height adjusts as it should. So things are working but it needs two clicks which I need to fix. Sorry I am still fairly new to coding so any tips would be great.

Comment: @AlfieWigley It would be a good idea if you could provide the relevant html so we can test the code

Comment: Did you mean to comment out the addEventListener in the provided code?  Adding a click handler during `onclick=` would do what you've described.   Without it your code is a little confusing as it loops `coll` for no reason - if there's an odd/even amount of `coll` it would / would not work.

Comment: The usual issue with "need to click twice" is when you have a condition to determine the first case.  Here, that is `if (content.style.height === "auto") {` - your expectation is that this will be true(or false) - it's not what you're expecting - so needs the following code to set to what you're expecting, so works on second call.  Debug what `content.style.height` actually is on the first click - alternatively, switch your if to `if (content.style.height !== "auto") { content.style.height = "auto"; } else ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is because `this` will refer to the `window` as the function was invoked via a `onclick` attribute.

As you're gone to the effort of including jQuery in the page, you should use that to attach your event handlers unobtrusively, and also to set the classes on the elements.

In addition, it's better practice to use CSS to update the UI, so simlpy toggling a class to set the height of the element would be a better approach. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(document).on('click', '.dropdown', e => {
    const $dd = $(e.currentTarget);
    $dd.find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');    
    $dd.siblings('.content').toggleClass('large');
  }); 
});
```

```css
.container {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.content { 
  margin: 20px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #C00; /* only for this demo to show the height change */
}

.content.large {
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="content">Title</div>
</div>
```

Finally, note that any CSS/styling should be placed in an external stylesheet, not in the HTML.

Comment: Thank you, the content large and content classes have helped we have also used 2 more lines of toggle class to get this working.     let coll = $(".dropdown");
    for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    //  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () { 
            $(element.firstElementChild).toggleClass('fa-chevron-down');
            $(element.firstElementChild).toggleClass('fa-chevron-up');
            $(element.nextElementSibling).toggleClass("content-min");
            $(element.nextElementSibling).toggleClass("content-max");

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the issue by replacing `this` with the `element` that the function takes as argument. Furthermore you should use `firstElementChild` instead of `firstChild`.

**Working example:**

(i simplified your example a bit)

```js
function dropdownbuttonclick(element) {
  let coll = $(".dropdown");
  
  $(element.firstElementChild).toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
  var content = element.nextElementSibling;

  if (content.style.height === "auto") {
    content.style.height = "75px";
  } 
  else {
    content.style.height = "auto";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="dropdown">
  <div width='100%' style='min-height:100px;'>
    <button 
      type='button' 
      class='dropdown' 
      onclick='dropdownbuttonclick(this)'
    >
      <i class='fa fa-solid fa-chevron-down'></i>
    </button>

    <div class='content' style='margin:20px;'>Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing with the first click it adds both classes (`fa-chevron-down` and `fa-chevron-up`) and the second, takes both classes out. Try separating them:

```js
$(this.firstChild).toggleClass('fa-chevron-down');
$(this.firstChild).toggleClass('fa-chevron-up');
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Hi Gloomy, we tried this version at first but they both do the same thing. The issue was that we had two click events happening, the first in the onclick in the button itself and then the second being the event listener click.